# Decode multiple video on GPU (FFmpeg.autogen + C#)

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, autogen

I'm trying to use the basic example about decoding video (FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example) in the FFmpeg.autogen 4.3.0.3 library https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen to decode multiple videos on a GPU (AMD radeon R7 430). My main function is as follows:

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = @".\abc.mp4";
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                url = @"D:\video\abc" + i + ".mp4";
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    DecodeAllFramesToImages(AVHWDeviceType.AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_D3D11VA, url);
                }).Start();
            }
        }
```

I try to decode video abc.mp4 with GPU Hardware Acceleration. However, an error occurs when i run thread count greater than 10. The error images is as follows:

- "System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory." [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zJoG.jpg)
- And in the console screen there is an error message "Failed to create D3D11VA video decoder" and "Failed setup for format d3d11: hwaccel innitialisation returned error"
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj3KS.jpg).

I'm new to the ffmpeg library recently, so I don't know the problem very well, I would love to have your help with this error!!

```
private static unsafe void DecodeAllFramesToImages(AVHWDeviceType HWDevice, string url)
        {             
            using (var vsd = new VideoStreamDecoder(url,HWDevice))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"codec name: {vsd.CodecName}");

                var info = vsd.GetContextInfo();
                info.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key} = {x.Value}"));

                var sourceSize = vsd.FrameSize;
                var sourcePixelFormat = HWDevice == AVHWDeviceType.AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_NONE ? vsd.PixelFormat : GetHWPixelFormat(HWDevice);
                var destinationSize = sourceSize;
                var destinationPixelFormat = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
                using (var vfc = new VideoFrameConverter(sourceSize, sourcePixelFormat, destinationSize, destinationPixelFormat))
                {
                    var frameNumber = 0;
                    while (vsd.TryDecodeNextFrame(out var frame))
                    {
                       //var convertedFrame = vfc.Convert(frame);                        
                       // using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(convertedFrame.width, convertedFrame.height, convertedFrame.linesize[0], PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr) convertedFrame.data[0]))
                       // bitmap.Save($"frame.{frameNumber:D8}.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        
                        Console.WriteLine($"frame: {frameNumber}");
                        frameNumber++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example
{
    public sealed unsafe class VideoStreamDecoder : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly AVCodecContext* _pCodecContext;
        private readonly AVFormatContext* _pFormatContext;
        private readonly int _streamIndex;
        private readonly AVFrame* _pFrame;
        private readonly AVFrame* _receivedFrame;
        private readonly AVPacket* _pPacket;

        public VideoStreamDecoder(string url, AVHWDeviceType HWDeviceType = AVHWDeviceType.AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_NONE)
        {
            _pFormatContext = ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context();
            _receivedFrame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();
            var pFormatContext = _pFormatContext;
            ffmpeg.avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, url, null, null).ThrowExceptionIfError();
            ffmpeg.avformat_find_stream_info(_pFormatContext, null).ThrowExceptionIfError();
            AVCodec* codec = null;
            _streamIndex = ffmpeg.av_find_best_stream(_pFormatContext, AVMediaType.AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &codec, 0).ThrowExceptionIfError();
            _pCodecContext = ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
            if (HWDeviceType != AVHWDeviceType.AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_NONE)
            {
                ffmpeg.av_hwdevice_ctx_create(&_pCodecContext->hw_device_ctx, HWDeviceType, null, null, 0).ThrowExceptionIfError();
            }
            ffmpeg.avcodec_parameters_to_context(_pCodecContext, _pFormatContext->streams[_streamIndex]->codecpar).ThrowExceptionIfError();
            ffmpeg.avcodec_open2(_pCodecContext, codec, null).ThrowExceptionIfError();            
            CodecName = ffmpeg.avcodec_get_name(codec->id);
            FrameSize = new Size(_pCodecContext->width, _pCodecContext->height);
            PixelFormat = _pCodecContext->pix_fmt;
            _pPacket = ffmpeg.av_packet_alloc();
            _pFrame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();
        }

        public string CodecName { get; }
        public Size FrameSize { get; }
        public AVPixelFormat PixelFormat { get; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(_pFrame);
            ffmpeg.av_free(_pFrame);

            ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(_pPacket);
            ffmpeg.av_free(_pPacket);

            ffmpeg.avcodec_close(_pCodecContext);
            var pFormatContext = _pFormatContext;
            ffmpeg.avformat_close_input(&pFormatContext);
        }

        public bool TryDecodeNextFrame(out AVFrame frame)
        {
            ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(_pFrame);
            ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(_receivedFrame);
            int error;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    do
                    {
                        error = ffmpeg.av_read_frame(_pFormatContext, _pPacket);
                        if (error == ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF)
                        {
                            frame = *_pFrame;
                            return false;
                        }

                        error.ThrowExceptionIfError();
                    } while (_pPacket->stream_index != _streamIndex);

                    ffmpeg.avcodec_send_packet(_pCodecContext, _pPacket).ThrowExceptionIfError();
                }
                finally
                {
                    ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(_pPacket);
                }

                error = ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame(_pCodecContext, _pFrame);
            } while (error == ffmpeg.AVERROR(ffmpeg.EAGAIN));
            error.ThrowExceptionIfError();
            if (_pCodecContext->hw_device_ctx != null)
            {
                ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(_receivedFrame, _pFrame, 0).ThrowExceptionIfError();
                frame = *_receivedFrame;
            }
            else
            {
                frame = *_pFrame;
            }
            return true;
        }
        public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> GetContextInfo()
        {
            AVDictionaryEntry* tag = null;
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            while ((tag = ffmpeg.av_dict_get(_pFormatContext->metadata, "", tag, ffmpeg.AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)) != null)
            {
                var key = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr) tag->key);
                var value = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr) tag->value);
                result.Add(key, value);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to decode multiple videos concurrently? If you only have one GPU it will probably just serialize the decoding anyway. However, you might want to move the saving of bitmaps to another thread, with some buffering in between. Saving bitmap will likely take longer than decoding the frames.

Comment: I want to play multiple camera video streams simultaneously on my desktop (up to 100 cameras maybe at a time). Therefore, to offloading for CPU, I would like to decode on GPU or Quick Sync Video.